# Unable to Store Session Variable On Form Submit

Tags: php, session

When I try to submit my form a to form b and load it to a new page using javascript window.open or alternatively the action="" attribute on the form tag itself, everything fires off correctly but on the new page load the SESSION variables are NOT passed. However if i take away the window.open method, submit the form and mannually load the new page in my browser, the SESSION variables do come up correctly in the input fields on the new page in form b...

I wondered if it had anything to do with the "return false;" part of the onsubmit function I have running on form a or if, on form submit and new page load, it's not setting the SESSION values before the SESSION stores them and loads the new page into the window... It has to be one of those two culprits. IT works if I don't do a page redirect, so I believe it's not actually storing the SESSION variables when the new page is loaded after submit... How can I correctly and successfully store the SESSION on the new page load so it loads correctly in the new page on form b?

INDEX FILE (FORM A)

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['cable_no'] = $_POST['cable_no'];
    $_SESSION['co_name'] = $_POST['co_name'];
    $_SESSION['prepping_team'] = $_POST['prepping_team'];
    $_SESSION['section_no'] = $_POST['section_no'];
    $_SESSION['tech_name_a'] = $_POST['tech_name_a'];
}
?>
<header>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js">       </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</header>
<form method="post" onsubmit="uploaddata(); return false;">
HTML CODE
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

JS FILE

```
function uploaddata() { 

//Read all of the data from the page
for (eID in prepform) {
    prepform[eID] = document.getElementById(eID).value;
}
//Send to database upload function and verify IF checkboxes are checked
if(document.getElementById("a11").checked && document.getElementById("b11").checked && document.getElementById("c11").checked && document.getElementById("a12").checked && document.getElementById("b12").checked && document.getElementById("c12").checked) {
        upload_prepform();
    }else{
        alert("Please verify that you have checked the known check boxes.")
    }
}   
function upload_prepform() {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './php/upload_prepform.php',
            data: prepform,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function() {
                alert("Thank you. Your Prep form has been submitted.");
            },

            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error... " + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
            },
            complete: function() {
                window.location.replace("http://dev1.rs.idmyasset.com/gp21-dev/prep_b/");
                alert("Redirecting...");
            }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must start file with

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

you can't use it after html code

Comment: I edited my post... I have it correct in my file on server, I posted it incorrectly on this post. Plus, it is all working except when I actually have to load the new page on form submit, but thanks for the fast reply anyway.

Comment: The return false seems to be the culprit at the moment... Is there a better way to run the function uploaddata(); so it fires off correctly?

Comment: there is no need of `return false`. you can remove it.

Comment: and you have `uploaddata();` function can you show me the code of it?

Comment: Sure, updated my question's JS code. upload_prepform is really the function uploaddata calls to. Uploaddata performs a check, if you will. I'm leaving out alot of code only because alot of it is used to submit data to SQL DB, so I didn't want to confuse you all, but looks like I managed to do that anyway haha

Comment: @jflay yah it is creating confusion :D, I am finding the solution

Comment: I have found that for my windows.location function:

    assign(url): Load the document at the provided URL.

    replace(url):Replace the current document with the one at the provided URL. The difference from the assign() method is that after using replace() the current page will not be saved in session history, meaning my session variables are not being saved... so what page load event do I need to use?

Comment: @jflay you can use javascript `window.history.back()` function to go back

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I want at all :( I think I have officially narrowed down the problem to be the javascript load event... I need to find a way to redirect the page AND save the session variables all at the same time because whatever I have going on now is killing the session.

Comment: I found the solution... all I needed to do was instead of using the session start and variables in my index.php I needed to just move it all over to my upload.php file (omitting the if isset statement) where I was sending all the data via AJAX anyway (to upload to SQL DB), so there it collects the data and loads it onto the next page successfully... thanks for all your help!